# Which Stack Exchange site is for my Mac/Chrome issue?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, google-chrome, mac

Apparently I made a boo-boo by asking why "[Text to speech won't work in Chrome anymore](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/111344/text-to-speech-wont-work-in-chrome-anymore?noredirect=1#comment98372_111344)" on the web applications Stack Exchange site.

So... which<sup>*</sup> Stack Exchange site is the right one for this question? I don't *think* the Apple Stack Exchange site is the right one, since this problem only happens with chrome, but I could be wrong.

---

<sup>*</sup>See what I did there? It's Halloween.

Comment: I'm confused. You're calling this a "Chrome" issue but it's specifically about Chrome failing to integrate properly with your Apple system preferences. Is there a specific reason you think Apple is wrong for this?

Comment: @Catija well, whenever I searched with "mac" all the results were about troubleshooting the mac text2speech but in my issue, text2speech does work with everything else, and used to work in chrome but now chrome only reads the webpage titles. That's why.

Answer (score 2):

[Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/macos) should be fine. It's probably [on topic on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) as well. Considering the TTS bits of many OSes are baked into the OS, not the browser, that it's browser specific should not matter.